# Qt4: How to change the default values (range, value, single step size) for QSpinBox for new instances?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt4.8, qspinbox

I'm using lot of QDoubleSpinBoxes in my project (with Qt 4.8.0), and for all of them, I want the same range, single step size, value etc., which are different from the default values though.

I wanted to ask: Is there a way to change these default values so that new instances of the QSpinBoxes will be created with the new default values so that I don't to have change in every time?

Simply said, instead of this:

```
QDoubleSpinBox *spin1 = new QDoubleSpinBox(this);
spin1->setSingleStep(0.03);
spin1->setDecimals(4);
spin1->setRange(2.0, 35.0);

QDoubleSpinBox *spin2 = new QDoubleSpinBox(this);
spin2->setSingleStep(0.03);
spin2->setDecimals(4);
spin2->setRange(2.0, 35.0);

...
```

I want something like this:

```
QDoubleSpinBox::setDefaultSingleStep(0.03);
QDoubleSpinBox::setDefaultDecimals(4);
QDoubleSpinBox::setDefaultRange(2.0, 35.0);

QDoubleSpinBox *spin1 = new QDoubleSpinBox(this);
QDoubleSpinBox *spin2 = new QDoubleSpinBox(this);
```

Does anyone know if this is possible and if yes, how?

Comment: Maybe easiest way for you is to subclass QDoubleSpinBox and set new defaults in constructor of new class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a factory, that creates the spin boxes with the desired values.

e.g.

```
class MySpinBoxFactory {
public:
   MySpinboxFactory(double singleStep, int decimals, double rangeMin, double rangeMax)
   : m_singleStep(singleStep), m_decimals(decimals), m_rangeMin(rangeMin), m_rangeMax(rangeMax) {}

   QDoubleSpinBox *createSpinBox(QWidget *parent = NULL) {
      QDoubleSpinBox *ret = new QDoubleSpinBox(parent);
      ret->setSingleStep(m_singleStep);
      ret->setDecimals(m_decimals);
      ret->setRange(m_rangeMin, m_rangeMax);
      return ret;
   }
private:
   double m_singleStep;
   int m_decimals;
   double m_rangeMin;
   double m_rangeMax;
}

// ...
MySpinboxFactory fac(0.03, 4, 2.0, 35.0);
QDoubleSpinBox *spin1 = fac.createSpinBox(this);
QDoubleSpinBox *spin2 = fac.createSpinBox(this);
```

You can also add setters to change the values. With this, you can create spinboxes with different default values using a single factory instance.

```
MySpinboxFactory fac(0.03, 4, 2.0, 35.0);
QDoubleSpinBox *spin1 = fac.createSpinBox(this);
QDoubleSpinBox *spin2 = fac.createSpinBox(this);

fac.setSingleStep(0.1);
QDoubleSpinBox *spin3 = fac.createSpinBox(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make your own new class derived from QDoubleSpinBox.  In your class constructor, set the values you want.